# ShieldPlugIn.class Missing from Shield 2.4.2

Tags: java, security, elasticsearch, connection, client

I'm upgrading the Elastic Cluster to 5.0.1, which doesn't work with Shield 2.4.1.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.elasticsearch.shield.ShieldPlugin overrides final method onModule.(Lorg/elasticsearch/action/ActionModule;)
```

Because of that, I'm trying to upgrade it to Shield 2.4.2, but then I'm facing an issue with missing ShieldPlugin.class. Is there a replacement class that is not documented?

Comment: I this ES 5.0.1 will only work with shield 5.0.1. It comes with x-pack now. https://www.elastic.co/downloads/x-pack

Comment: That's what I found out as well. The problem is that there is no way to get it working with Java API right now when using their cloud service. I ran into certificate issue.

Comment: If you run into an issue with connection to 5.x instance, take a look at some info here which might fix your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981855/connecting-to-elasticsearch-cloud-5-x-with-java-client-and-x-pack-https